# How do I write this without global variables?

Tags: python, function, global-variables, local-variables

I have to write a program that takes input and writes out the number entered along with the grade it would be. My program works but apparently I am only supposed to use local variables. What do I need to change so that it is only local variables? The two variables below are what I currently use as global variables.

```
# This program takes intger inputs and provides a grade value for each number entered

number = 1
myNumbers = []

print("Please enter as many integer numbers as you would like. Enter -999 to exit loop")
# This function has the user input values and exit with a sentinel value -999
def getScores(number):
    sentinelValue = -999

    while(number != sentinelValue):
        number = eval(input("Enter an integer: "))

        if number > -1:
             myNumbers.append(number)

    print("Numbers entered: ")
    print(myNumbers, "\n")


# This function prints out the values with the appropriate letter grade
def printScores():

    print("Length of array = ", len(myNumbers))

    for i in range(0, len(myNumbers)):

        if myNumbers[i] >= 90:
            print(myNumbers[i], "is an A")
        if myNumbers[i] >= 80 and myNumbers[i] < 90:
            print(myNumbers[i], "is a B")
        if myNumbers[i] >= 70 and myNumbers[i] < 80:
            print(myNumbers[i], "is a C")
        if myNumbers[i] >= 60 and myNumbers[i] < 70:
            print(myNumbers[i], "is a D")
        if myNumbers[i] >= 0 and myNumbers[i] < 60:
            print(myNumbers[i], "is an F")
# The main function is where we will call the other functions and print out the results
def main():

    getScores(number)
    printScores()

# Call the main
main()
```

I am still supposed to have the two separate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getScores` doesn't need a number on input... it can just create a default value before the loop. It can return the list it creates instead of writing a global variable. The caller remembers that return value and uses it in the next call.

```
# This program takes intger inputs and provides a grade value for each number entered

print("Please enter as many integer numbers as you would like. Enter -999 to exit loop")
# This function has the user input values and exit with a sentinel value -999
def getScores():
    sentinelValue = -999
    number = ''
    myNumbers = []
    while(number != sentinelValue):
        number = eval(input("Enter an integer: "))

        if number > -1:
             myNumbers.append(number)

    print("Numbers entered: ")
    print(myNumbers, "\n")
    return myNumbers

# This function prints out the values with the appropriate letter grade
def printScores(myNumbers):

    print("Length of array = ", len(myNumbers))
    # omit the rest for brevity...

# The main function is where we will call the other functions and print out the results
def main():
    scores = getScores()
    printScores(scores)

# Call the main
main()
```

Comment: I get an error for main(), scores = getScores(number), and a "NameError: name 'number' is not defined"

Comment: My bad... some copy/paste error I think. The updated code works.